# Magento - upgrade a store that was installed without authentication key

Tags: magento2.2, magento-2.1.9, magento2.3.0

I have a `magento 2.1.9` and i want to upgrade it to `magento 2.2.0` (or if possible straight to `magento 2.3.0` even tho i think that that's not possible because of php version). But when the store was installed there was no authentication public/private key used. How do i upgrade my magento in this scenario?

P.S: My store has around 900 products, ~2000 orders and customers,and i would like to keep them. :(

Answer (score 2):

Yes you would be needing authentication keys to upgrade your store.

You can get authentication public/private keys from marketplace. Refer to [official doc](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html) how you can get the keys

Comment: Hey @Priyank, but i don't have the original keys or things like that, a guy installed if for me a few months ago and i can't get in touch with him. Is it ok if i create my own keys?

Comment: Ya I guess it should work with new keys.

Comment: X_X @Priyank, you guess or you know it? X_X :D

Comment: I have always used my keys. Never tried by changing it. So its a guess it may work.